# How to reference super class in constructor in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, constructor, initialization, super

I have a class that extends a class, and implements an interface by delegation. However, when initializing the delegate object, I want to pass a protected property of the superclass. How can I access it? I've tried writing the property name by itself, and accessing `super.property` but neither works. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: It is not possible. The delegate has to be instantiated before the class that is using it, so you can't use any properties of this class or its superclass.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the delegate object first and do your setup after the constructor of your class is done.

If the property you need to access is private or hidden, you will need some custom method to pass the property to the delegate.

Perhaps you might want to rethink your strategy for initialization, and consider a build pattern. Yet it would help us if you where to provide some sample code and explain more in detail.